# CSS - margin between flex grid

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple grid layout created with flex, I want to have a grid of 3x3 blocks with a margin between each block.

If I add a margin it makes it 2x5.

How can I have it 3x3 with a margin between each block

```css
.wrap{
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block{
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you use 32% width of block you have 3x3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your desired result by using a flexbox property `justify-content: space-between;` which takes up the remaining space of the elements and spreads that between them

so all I did is made the width slightly smaller than 33% so we have remaining space and added `justify-content: space-between;` to the wrapper

```css
.wrap{
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block{
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `calc` function to subtract the margin (10px = 5px on each side) and also specify `box-sizing: border-box` on all your HTML elements so you don't have to include the border in your calculations.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.wrap{
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block{
  width: calc(33.3333% - 10px);
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```